# In the circuit below, assume ideal op-amp, find Vx?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, constant-current

Assuming ideal op-amp, I have this question that asks to find Vx:

[image]

Here is my solution, how can I verify my solution? Can anyone check please?
[image]

Ok, after seeing the comments, I tried again and got this solution, is it more logical now? and which one shall I adop?

[image]

Comment: Yousef, Here are some initial hints: The circuit maintains a constant current through the 1k resistor on the right (and accordingly, a constant voltage drop across it). This current is split in two with half (1mA) flowing through R3 to the right. I think you will now be able to easily determine Vx (ChatGPT will be able to :-) What the AI couldn't do (thank goodness, at least for now) is figure out what the basic idea behind the circuit is and explain it to us...

Comment: ... So if I had to choose between your two versions, I would prefer the first one. But perhaps the fact that the circuit is inverting with respect to Vin should be taken into account.

Comment: @Yousef Your analysis is not correct. The gain is (-1.25). For a derivation see my detailed answer.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I saw the circuit diagram with the input voltage Vin=1 volt - and the result. I realized too late that your result is valid for another voltage Vin.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution appears correct for a brief instant, however the op-amp is not balanced with Vx = 5V, there is -1.67V differential voltage, so the output will stabilize at a lower voltage.

I'm not sure what they are getting at showing the value of current I1, since it can not persist. Maybe they want you to check for balance, or maybe the question is just sloppy.

Comment: Looks like an "improved Howland current source" with 3 k load (then I1 has some sense).

Comment: So my solution had to be correct right?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist except if that's the intention there is an error in the resistor values- the 'top' 1kΩ could be 2kΩ, for example, and it would work. So either the professor is trying to teach a lesson on making assumptions or it's just a sloppy circuit (or maybe OP made an error transcribing it). Since we don't know the source, it's hard to even guess probabilities).

Comment: I uploaded a newer solution, will you check it please? Is it more logical now? and shall I go for it? @SpehroPefhany

Comment: Spehro Pefhany, I continued to look for the basic idea in this weird circuit solution and came to the conclusion that it is indeed the classic "improved Howland current pump". Only, the 'top' 1kΩ resistor really should be 1kΩ since Vx must follow VL across the 3 k load. So, dVx = 2/3*3/2*dVL = dVL and the voltage drop across the right 1 k stays constant while RL, accordingly VL (VR3), varies. As a result, the load current through R3 is constant. Maybe I should assemble some "CircuitLab comics" tomorrow...

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask "how can I verify this solution?", you can simulate the circuit in [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/), or any simulator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPycDV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Doing so would have immediately highlighted the fact that if \$V_{IN}=+1V\$, then \$I_1\$ cannot possibly be the advertised value of \$I_1 = 1mA\$. From the above circuit it's clear that for the condition \$I_1 = 1mA\$ to be true, then there's only one solution: \$V_{IN}=-4V\$.

Therefore the original question seems to have a problem.

The good news is that your first solution for \$V_X\$ was correct: \$V_X=+5V\$, if the condition you aim to satisfy is \$I_1=1mA\$.

The second solution, \$V_X=+2.5V\$ corresponds to \$V_{IN}=-2V\$ and \$I_1=0.5mA\$, neither of which agrees with \$V_{IN}\$ and \$I_1\$ in the original diagram.

My arithmetic for this circuit is:

$$ V_X = -\frac{5}{4}V_{IN} $$

$$ I_1 = \frac{V_X}{5000} = -\frac{V_{IN}}{4000}$$

Comment: The problem of this "improved Howland current source" is that it is poorly designed. The R4-R5 voltage divider must be of high resistance (e.g., R4 = 200 k, R5 = 100 k) so as not to significantly load the R3-R6 divider. Then, if Vin = 1 V, Vx would be -1 V and the current -0.5 mA. Obviously this was done deliberately for some purpose.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I wish this was obvious to me too! Regardless of the purpose of the design, the task is simply to find \$V_X\$, and the conditions \$V_{IN}=+1V\$ and \$I_1=1mA\$ are at odds. The only obvious thing I see here is that the question, as shown, is incoherent.

Comment: @Simon Fitch The output is Vx=+5V for an input of Vin=-4V. So the gain is (-1.25) - and this gain is in accordance with my answer. However, the questioners "first solution" is NOT correct, because he has assumed an input of Vin=1V

Comment: @Simon Fitch I also got Vx = +5 V when I simulated the circuit in LTSpice, but now - and regardless everything - the second solution seems also true, so why is that possible? I showed my both solutions to my professor he was surprised that both seems to be finely correct but with different answers! Thanks for your time.

Comment: @YousefZerini By my calculations, your second answer \$V_X=+2.5V\$ gives \$V_{IN}=-2V\$ and \$I_1=0.5mA\$. I don't see how this is a "correct" answer, since it disagrees with *both* conditions \$V_{IN}=+1V\$ and \$I_1=1mA\$.

Comment: I think, there is only one single solution for the gain (referring to Vx) - and that is "-1.25". And, of course, this holds for any value for Vin - as long as the opamp is in its linear amplifying region.

Comment: I noticed that such basic questions have decreased a lot here and I started to wonder why. Finally I found the explanation - schools are on vacation and these are "textbook questions".

Answer (score 1):

I read to fast your question and didn't notice the positive feedback. So this book might still be useful, but not at page 400. It seems you are designing the Howland current pump. You should search for that, you'll find the solution.

This book is really useful for those questions. Go to page 400 ish. And keep it, you'll use it again!
https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Short calculation (voltage divider rules):

- V+=Vx[(3||3)/(3||3 + 1)] * (2/(1+2)) = Vx(1.5/2.5)*(2/3)= 0.4Vx
- V-=Vx(2/3)=0.666Vx
- V- larger than V+ ; circuit is stable
- Total feedback factor: Hr=(V+)-(V-)=0.4-0.666=-0.2666
- Forward factor (input damping): Hf=1/3=0.333

**Gain: Vx/Vin=Hf/Hr=-1.25**

Answer (score 0):

## Demystifying the "improved Howland current source"

There are circuit solutions that are legends; this is one of them. It is inadmissible to analyze them without mentioning their names, which are most often those of their inventors. To do so is like explaining the construction of an iron tower without mentioning that it is the Eiffel Tower. It is also unacceptable to blindly analyze something so significant without explaining what it does; circuitry is not simply algebra. Here I will try to fill that lack.

This is a circuit that keeps the current constant regardless of load changes by varying the supply voltage. To show how it does it, I will build the circuit step by step using CircuitLab. To simplify the calculations, I will use more convenient equal resistances in these conceptual schematics.

### Building the circuit

**STEP 1:** The task is to create a 1 mA constant current source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXbGen.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**STEP 2:** We make it in the well-known way - by connecting a 1 k resistor RI in series to a 1 V input voltage source Vin. The circuit is simple but perfect since the load is an "ideal"ammeter with zero internal resistance. The current is simply determined by Ohm's law - IL = Vin/RI.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbFWUj.png)</sup>

**STEP 3:** But if we connect an imperfect ammeter with 1 k internal resistance, the current decreases - IL = Vin/(RI + RL) = 0.5 mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQOTyn.png)</sup>

**STEP 4:** Obviously we need to compensate somehow for the unwanted load resistance. The first idea that comes to mind, and which is the essence of this circuit, is ***to increase the voltage by as much as is lost on the load***. Then the current will restore its initial value - IL = (Vin + VL - VL)/RI = Vin/RL. Great! Let's do it by the help of CircuitLab.

Open the Vin *parameters* window and begin increasing the voltage while looking at the ammeter. Stop when IL =1 mA. Of course, you can directly increase Vin with 1 V but this is closer to the way the original circuit does it. So we made a "man-controlled current source".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJKA08.png)</sup>

**STEP 5:** Now all that remains is to assign this routine work to an op-amp. Adding two resistors R1 and R2 to it, we assemble an *inverting amplifier* acting as the input voltage source. To make it follow VL, we have to apply VL/2 to its non-inverting input thus making it act as a *non-inverting amplifier* with gain of 2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIpbgf.png)</sup>

**STEP 6:** Where do we get VL/2 from? Of course, with the help of a voltage divider (R3-R4) connected to the load. This divider must not divert from the load current; so let's choose R3 = R4 = 100 k.

To check if our creation works correctly, let's start changing the load resistance - first manually and then automatically using the CircuitLab *DC sweep*.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3xGh0.png)</sup>

Great! VL is "shifted" with the constant voltage drop VRI to Vx...

[image: STEP 6_1]

... so the load current is constant as well - IL = (Vx - VL)/RI = 1 mA.

[image: STEP 6_2]

**STEP 7:** But how do we calculate VRI? It turns out this is extremely simple. Imagine the initial state when the load has zero resistance. The voltage at the non-inverting input is zero and the circuit is a humble inverting amplifier. We can simplify it by removing the unnecessary resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkYP7g.png)</sup>

VRI is simply the op-amp output voltage Vx = -Vin*R2/R1 = 1 V. When VL increases, Vx follows its variations; so VRI stays constant (1 V).

### Worsening the circuit (OP's version)

Finally, let's put ourselves in the shoes of the OP's professor who has to create problems for their students to make them think. I don't think this is the best way, but let's try. We have to corrupt something in the circuit and the poor R3-R4 voltage divider sticks in our eyes. Well, we reduce the resistance of its resistors by a hundred times so that it diverts a significant current from the load...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3m5aC.png)</sup>

... and we enjoy the effect of our damage.

[image: STEP 7_1]

[image: STEP 7_2]